# Powershell: Expand-Archive: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'

Tags: powershell, zip

I'm trying to run a powershell command to extract all zip files into a folder to a new path.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command Get-ChildItem 'Z:\audio\music\purchased-music\incoming' -Filter *.zip | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath 'Z:\audio\music\purchased-music\incoming-unzipped' -Force
```

It looks like the command should work, but I get an error as such:

```
Expand-Archive : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:140
+ ... ter *.zip | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath 'Z:\audio\music\purchased ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:PSObject) [Expand-Archive], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Expand-Archive

Expand-Archive : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:140
+ ... ter *.zip | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath 'Z:\audio\music\purchased ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:PSObject) [Expand-Archive], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Expand-Archive

Expand-Archive : The path '    Directory: Z:\audio\music\purchased-music\incoming' either does not exist or is not a valid file system path.
At line:1 char:140
+ ... ter *.zip | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath 'Z:\audio\music\purchased ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (    Directory: ...-music\incoming:String) [Expand-Archive], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArchiveCmdletPathNotFound,Expand-Archive
```

The path and destination both do exist:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command Get-ChildItem 'Z:\audio\music\purchased-music\incoming' -Filter *.zip                                             

    Directory: Z:\audio\music\purchased-music\incoming


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----          2/6/2021   4:28 PM       38489484 Satsuma.zip
```

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> dir Z:\audio\music\purchased-music\incoming-unzipped


    Directory: Z:\audio\music\purchased-music\incoming-unzipped


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        12/16/2020   2:15 AM          20320 touch.txt
```

Comment: You might (re-)read the help for `powershell /?`. You have to wrap the command you provide for the Powershell executable in curly braces. There are even examples showing how to use it. ;-)  ... regardless of that - why are you calling Powershell from inside of Powershell? You could simply run the command as it is.

Comment: Appologies, as I'm not a powershell user generally.  I started by looking for a way to extract an archive from the task scheduler and calling powershell Extract-Archive is what I found.  Looks like me testing it out through powershell itself is part of why it's failing.  It actually works when called from task scheduler.

Comment: No need to appologize. We all started once.  ;-)   Did you read the help? Did you see the examples? Did you try to wrap your command in curly braces?

Comment: Thanks!  Seems to work for me without the brackets.   I was just tripped up by formulating the command to be called inside task scheduler.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on [Olaf's helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66082598/powershell-expand-archive-cannot-validate-argument-on-parameter-path#comment116834614_66082598), this would work with braces as per `powershell /?`, or [about_PowerShell_exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-command) documentation:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command {Get-ChildItem 'Z:\audio\music\purchased-music\incoming' -Filter *.zip | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath 'Z:\audio\music\purchased-music\incoming-unzipped' -Force}
```

Since you're using PowerShell, you  don't need to launch the exe to execute a command:

```
Get-ChildItem 'Z:\audio\music\purchased-music\incoming' -Filter *.zip |
Expand-Archive -DestinationPath 'Z:\audio\music\purchased-music\incoming-unzipped' -Force
```

(the `PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>` isn't relevant to code execution as you're specifying full paths `Z:\audio\...` etc - you could be running this from any location)

Comment: The second example works for me - I was just tripped up by trying to test what I needed to call in Task Scheduler.   The next problem I'm trying to address is getting the DestinationPath to be ..\incoming-unzipped\<original archivename>.   Outside the scope of this original question perhaps.

Comment: @GeoffMaddock It is.... I suggest searching stackoverflow for 'expand archive destinationpath' and looking at a few of those -  free to raise another question if you don't find an answer:)